# Ionic1 Factory Update and return changes

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I have an ionic1 application which uses a factory / service.

```
.factory('expenses', function($http) {

    var expenseCategories = [];

    return {

        getCategories: function(){

            return expenseCategories;

        },

        updateCategories: function(){

            return $http.get('URL_HERE').then(function(response){

                return expenseCategories = response.data.data[0];

            });

        },

        storeCategory: function(category){

            $http({
                method: 'POST', 
                data: category,
                url: 'URL_HERE',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")}
            }).success(function(data) {

                expenseCategories = data.data[0];

            }).error(function(error){

            });

        }

    }

})
```

In my controller I'm calling the service on page load to show the categories, if no categories are found in the service it then checks the API and updates the categories in the service.

```
if(expenses.getCategories().length != 0){
      $scope.data.expenses = expenses.getCategories();
  } else {
      $scope.data.expenses = expenses.updateCategories();
  };
```

After updating, the user may want to add another category. After submitting to my API the controller calls the getCategories() function again but this isn't updating the categories currently in the DOM. I have to refresh the page to get the latest categories?

```
$scope.storeCategory = function()
  {

    expenses.storeCategory($scope.form);
    $scope.data.expenses = expenses.getCategories();
    $scope.closeModal();

  }
```

for reference here's my entire controller

```
.controller('expenseCategoryCtrl', function($scope, $state, expenses, $ionicModal, $http) {

  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.form = {};

  if(expenses.getCategories().length != 0){
      $scope.data.expenses = expenses.getCategories();
  } else {
      $scope.data.expenses = expenses.updateCategories();
  };

  $scope.storeCategory = function()
  {

    expenses.storeCategory($scope.form);
    $scope.data.expenses = expenses.getCategories();
    $scope.closeModal();

  }

});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.storeCategory = function()
  {

    expenses.storeCategory($scope.form);
    $scope.data.expenses = expenses.getCategories();
    $scope.closeModal();

  }
```

change to

```
$scope.storeCategory = function()
  {

    expenses.storeCategory($scope.form).then(function(data){
        $scope.data.expenses = expenses.getCategories();
        $scope.closeModal();
    });
  };
```

The storeCategory must be a promise, and the logic to reload the infor of categories must be when success those promise, hope helps.

Comment: Thanks for that I was able to debug and get it working :)

Comment: Great!! , glad those help you